# How to make Dynamic Term Link based on content type?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, uri

My web site has three content types ( Event, Course, Video) and 2 taxonomies(city and schools)
All of them have same taxonomy referenced field.
Eg:New York City events or New York City courses will be listed seperately.

**Problem:**
How can I make term links dynamic based on content type .

All new york city contents are listing(3 content type contents) if I clicked newyork city term on event content.

I need only event type contents to be listed if I came from an event type content. It should be changed according to  event,course or video content type.
Any help with this would be awesome . Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using Views.

The links rendered in Taxonomy fields (Entity reference fields) are set to go to Taxonomy term pages. The links are constructed with Taxonomy term ID in the URL: `taxonomy/term/[TID]`.

Taxonomy term pages are created using Views, so you can easily Edit the relevant Views to adjust it to your needs. The modification you're after is adding a Contextual filter that filters out only one content type.

With that modification you could type, for example, `taxonomy/term/10/article` in the browser address bar, and the usual Term page for term 10 would list only results of the Article Content Type.

The other part of your question is how to make the Taxonomy reference link on the node View be sensitive to the Content type it's on, so when it's clicked it goes to the filtered list, and not the general term page that shows all results.

The easiest way to do that is to hide that field from displaying and replace it with a Views Block that would output a similar link, only Contextually sensitive to the term, and to the Content type.

Here are the steps on how to achieve this:

### Make term pages sensitive to Content types

1. Duplicate the `Taxonomy term` View (it's better to keep the default ones as they are, so you don't mess up the original features and it makes updates more straightforward). Rename it to make sense (Taxonomy term-Content type)
2. Add a new Contextual Filter **Content type** from the `Content` Category (keep the one sensitive to the taxonomy term that is already there, we need it) and configure it with these options:
   `When the filter value is NOT in the URL`
   **Display all results for the specified field**
   `When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided`
   **Override title**
   **Content tagged with {{ arguments.tid }} of type {{ arguments.type }}**
   **Specify validation criteria**
   `Validator` **Content type**
   **Validate user has access to the Content type**
   `More`
   **Transform spaces to dashes in URL**
3. Edit the `Path` to add another `%` to react to the Contextual filter we just added, so you end up with the Path: `taxonomy/term/%/%`
4. Go to the other Display in the same View called `Feed` and edit the Path there to read `taxonomy/term/%/%/feed`
5. Save the View. You can test it by entering the relevant arguments into Preview inside Views (for example `10/article`) or by typing the URL into your browser addressbar (`example.com/taxonomy/term/10/article`).
6. Optional but good UX: add **No results behavior** **Text area** `No content of type {{ arguments.type }} tagged with {{ arguments.tid }} has been found.` on your Page display and override for that Display only **This page (override)**.

### Create taxonomy links on Nodes sensitive to CT

To create links sensitive to the context we need Views Display **Block** of type Content. We can add it to the Views we created above (because that View is of type Content), or create a completely new View for this. Since this Block Views will be sufficiently different it's better to create a new View for this. Here are the steps for adding a new  Views to accomplish this:

1. Create a new Views of type Content showing Fields, add a Block Display to the View, change its name to something meaningful you can recognize later on Blocks page: `Taxonomy term link sensitive to CT`
2. Add a Filter to limit to your desired Content types (event, course, video)
3. Under `Format` option `Show` settings choose to **Hide empty fields**
4. Add a new Field **City** (or whatever your field is called), **Exclude from display**, and **don't** tick `Link label to the referenced entity`
5. Add a new Field `Content type`, **Exclude from display** and set `Formatter` to **Entity ID** (so you get CT machine name so the contextual filter later works correctly)
6. Add a new Relationship **Taxonomy term referenced from field_city** and **Require this relationship**
7. Add a new Field **Term ID** (it will use the Relationship from previous step), **Exclude from display** and set `Formatter` to **Unformatted**
8. Add a new Field **Custom text** from `Global` Category and configure it:
   **Create a label** just tomake it easier to build, enter `Taxonomy link sensitive to CT`
   In **Text** area enter `{{ field_city }} (type { type }})`
   `Rewrite results`
   **Output this field as a custom link**
   **Link path**: `taxonomy/term/{{ tid }}/{{ type }}`
   **Replace spaces with dashes**
   `No results behavior`
   **Hide if empty**
9. Add a new Contextual filter **ID** from `Content` Category and configure:
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **Content ID from URL**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **Content**
   [your CTs video course event]

   Now when you enter a node ID into Preview it will show the link to taxonomy term page that has content type argument added to it at the end.
10. Set `Pager` to **Display a specified number of items** to `1` item
11. Remove the Title field so you end up with only the Custom text visible and Save the View
12. Place the Block in `Content` region, don't `Display title`, set `Content ID` to **Node from URL**, limit which Content type to show the Block on
13. Edit your Content types (all three) `Manage Display` to hide the City Taxonomy Field (drag to **Disabled**)

And now you have the relavant Taxonomy term link that has the added Content type at the end to call on Views term page that will filter out only that content type.

Comment: You seem to be using D7 while I wrote the examples for D8. Instead of the Entity ID format simply choose `Output machine name`, it's the same thing. Set the City field Formatter to Plain text, same this as unticking the option in D8 I mentioned. The Contextual filters on the first View shouldn't be with depth, there should only be one of those, and one of Content type, change the Path... There are still steps you need to do, it's all equivalent in D7.

Comment: I mean, there's no formatter option  for content type field.(5.item you mentioned)

Comment: Yes, I understood you, and I gave you an alternative for D7 in the comment, it's a standalone checkbox option, not a Formatter option.

Comment: I tried many combination since afternoon but it doesn't work or I could not make it... I have to find another way or give up..
Thanks for your support,really appreciated.

Comment: I fixed it for ya, Drupal 7 has slightly different syntax for tokens and arguments. You also hadn't selected all content types where you should had, you only included Event. But now the problem is the bock appears only on Events, because you haven't used the same City field on all relevant content types, you created new fields with new machine names. You should remove the extra City fields from video and course CTs and add **existing** City field to both CTs (watch for the machine name field_city). Then it will work as expected.

Comment: Many thanks prkos, I'm gonna check it and give feedback

Comment: It works with ../taxonomy/term/191/event.
It doesn't work when I change url alias.
I need your advice how to make it works witk link as ...city/newyork-city/event.. 
Thanks

Comment: That's to do with adjusting the Path and Relationships to introduce more information into Contextual filters. You should post another question about this, give the information you have about your Views using contextual filters and that you want the term name instead of TID in the URL.

Comment: I tried [term:vocabulary]/[term:name]/%/% for the path .It didn't work because token is not working at path. Anyway; many many thanks for support and time , really appreciated.

Comment: As I said you don't have the information in Views you want to use as tokens in Path, you need to add a Relationship. New question?